# Go to the below row in PHP

Tags: php

I know it sounds like a silly question.
But this is the first time in 3 years that I need this :(

I have mySQL loop that gives me some values.

What I need to do is to make the PHP write the values each one on a separated row.

```
function getMetaTags($page) {
$q='SELECT * FROM injections WHERE Page="'.$page.'" AND Type="META"';
 $r=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
      $meta .= $row['Content'];
       }
 return $meta;
}
```

Should return this:

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
```

AND NOT

```
<meta name="description" content=""><meta name="keywords" content="">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you just need this:

```
$meta .= $row['Content']."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

If a metaname = a $row :

```
$meta .= $row['Content'] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

For an operating system friendly approach, meaning it will work cross platform.

```
$meta .= $row['Content'].PHP_EOL;
```